# key value with dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling how to use key, value. This works:

```
for col, val in zip(rawData.columns, out):
   print((col), ':', round(val, 2))

a: 2.05
b: 1.98
c: 2.01
d: 1.98
```

Instead of printing the result like above, however, I now want to put the results in a dataframe

```
dw = pd.DataFrame()
for col, val in zip(rawData.columns, out):
    dw[f'test ({col})'] = val
```

This yields a blank dataframe:

```
     test(a)    test(b)     test(c)   test(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign single value to empty dataframe. so you can store the value in list `[val]` then assign.

```
for col, val in zip(rawData.columns, out):
    dw[f'test ({col})'] = [val]
```